# ListPopupWindow : Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()

Tags: android

I get this crash in strict mode on one device only (LG G2 Android 4.2.2). This happens in I click on the spinner(dropDown) and then tap on area outside the list dropdown and then navigate away from the parent activity.

```
05-20 14:39:55.099  20042-20042/** E/StrictMode? null
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity **.Activity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ListPopupWindow$1@4278add0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:795)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:596)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1405)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1385)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1379)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:423)
            at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:546)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:983)
            at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:610)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17634)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score -1):

unregister your receiver inside `onPause()` method. You have to register your receiver in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()` to prevent memory leaks

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(yourReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
}
```

Comment: I am not registering any receiver, according to StackTrace its registered by android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show()